# delete statement with a having count(*) > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some duplication's in a table that I wish to delete. However SQL doesn't like my query below.

```
delete from tblS
where Field = 'spread'
group by FundCode, Region, DateEntered
having count(*) > 1
```

So i tried the below query again though SQL doesn't like this. How should my query look?

```
delete s
from tblS s
join
(
    select FundCode, Region, DateEntered, count(*)
    from tblS 
    where Field = 'spread'
    group by FundCode, Region, DateEntered
    having count(*) > 1
) as d on s.FundCode = d.FundCode and s.DateEntered = d.DateEntered and s.Region= d.Region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when you want to delete duplicates, you want to keep one of them. The right function to use is `row_number()` and SQL Server supports updatable CTEs.  So:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by FundCode, Region, DateEntered order by FundCode) as seqnum
      from tblS t
      where Field = 'spread'
     )
delete toupdate
    where seqnum > 1;
```

If you actually want to delete *all* duplicates, then use `count(*)` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes I want to delete all duplicates, we have no need to keep them in this case thanks